How to get all customer reviews from App Store Connect API without getting rate limit exception?
We have approximately 75,000 customer reviews in AppStoreConnect across all of our apps. Is there a way to fetch all customer reviews without getting rate limit exception?
using Customer Reviews API to fetch customer reviews and iterating through the next in links object to get paginated data.
"links": {
        "self": "https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/apps/<id>/customerReviews?include=response&limit=200&sort=-createdDate",
        "next": "https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/apps/<id>/customerReviews?cursor=<value>&include=response&limit=200&sort=-createdDate"
    },

I don't know when the rate limit is getting triggered. So I want to filter the reviews by created date. Is there a way to filter the reviews based on created date?

Is this an actual programming-related question, if so then please add enough code to create an actual [mre]. Furthermore, how is this different than your previously asked question?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/identifying_rate_limits: "The limits apply to requests you send using the same API key." - if you can use different keys, that might be an option. If not, then you will have to throttle your requests / create a queue that will subsequently get worked through over time.

"Is there a way to filter the reviews based on created date?" - according to the documentation of the parameters of that endpoint: No. You can filter by specific rating value and/or by territory - but that appears to be it.

You can sort by created date however - so if you request them in descending order, you can stop when you encounter the first one you already fetched at some earlier point - so that might be an option to not have to go over the full set of reviews every single time.
